# Wget - Download pics with particular url string

Tags: wget

Is there a Wget command that will allow me to download all jpegs that include the following url:

http://www.sample.com/images/imag/

So all jpegs under that particular url will be downloaded, such as the following:

- http://www.sample.com/images/imag/%281665%29-253.jpg
- http://www.sample.com/images/imag/(2816)-2234.jpg
- http://www.sample.com/images/imag/32r4344sdfa.jpg
- http://www.sample.com/images/imag/dwedjpao.jpg

Regardless of whether the jpegs have different naming conventions.

Comment: `wget -A jpg -r http://www.sample.com/images/imag/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget -r -A jpg,jpeg http://www.sample.com/images/imag/`

This will create the entire directory tree.  If you don't want a directory tree, use:

`wget -r -A jpg,jpeg -nd http://www.sample.com/images/imag`

Alternatively, connect to `sample.com` (e.g. via ssh) and locate the `/images/imag` folder `ls *.jp* > foo.txt`, `wget -i -F foo.txt -B http://www.sample.com/images/imag/foo.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you "get" http://www.sample.com/images/imag/ image list.

If it is a page that include the images in a HTML document you could try something like this:

```
wget -nd -p -A jpg,jpeg -e robots=off http://...
```

Where:

- `-nd` : No directories. `--no-directories`
- `-p` : Include images (Page requisites) `--page-requisites`
- `-A` : Comma separated list of file name suffixes or patterns to accept. `--accept`
- `-e` : Execute command as if part of *.wgetrc*. `--execute`

  - Here; robots=off

---

Some servers only delivers compressed HTML, i.e. gzip. Then you have to take some extra measures as wget won't unpack and parse these (AFAIK). A rather quick and painless solution is using [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/).

After install make `wget` use the proxy by:

```
export http_proxy="http://localhost:8118"
```

then run command again.